# Getting different results using aggregate() and sum() functions in R

Tags: sum, aggregate

I'm trying to get a summary data frame of the total quantities of the variables `prop.damage` and `crop.damage` by `STATE` variable using the `aggregate()` function in R with the following code:

```
stormdata$prop.damage <- with(stormdata, ifelse(PROPDMGEXP == 'K', (PROPDMG * 10^3), ifelse(PROPDMGEXP == 'M', (PROPDMG * 10^6), ifelse(PROPDMGEXP == 'B', (PROPDMG * 10^9), NA))))
stormdata$crop.damage <- with(stormdata, ifelse(CROPDMGEXP == 'K', (CROPDMG * 10^3), ifelse(CROPDMGEXP == 'M', (CROPDMG * 10^6), ifelse(CROPDMGEXP == 'B', (CROPDMG * 10^9), NA))))
damagecost <- with(stormdata, aggregate(x = prop.damage + crop.damage, by = list(STATE), FUN = sum, na.rm = TRUE))
damagecost <- damagecost[order(damagecost$x, decreasing = TRUE), ]
```

Here the `PROPDMGEXP` and `CROPDMGEXP` variables are used as a multiplier for the `PROPDMG` and `CROPDMG` numeric variables. My main data set is `stormdata`.

And I get the following:

```
> head(damagecost)
   Group.1            x
8       CA 120211639720
13      FL  27302948100
38      MS  14804212820
63      TX  12550131850
20      IL  11655920860
2       AL   9505473250
```

But, for example, If I do the addition "manually" for California ('CA') I get this:

```
> sum(stormdata$prop.damage[stormdata$STATE == 'CA'], na.rm = TRUE) + sum(stormdata$crop.damage[stormdata$STATE == 'CA'], na.rm = TRUE)
[1] 127115859410
```

I don't understand why I'm getting different results.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that both variables `prop.damage` and `crop.damage` had `NA` values within them and those `NAs` were affecting the result when the variables were added in the `aggregate` function.

Comment: So what is the final conclusion? Could you elaborate your findings?