# How is using aggregate function in R vs sum(Dataframe$columns)/N different?

Tags: r, aggregate, average

I have a dataframe X that looks like this:

```
A B C D E Identifier  
1 2 3 4 5          a  
2 3 2 2 1          b  
4 5 4 5 3          a   
2 3 4 5 6          a  
0 0 1 2 3          a  
1 2 1 1 1          b
```

(here the range is 6 as the period over which observations are recorded is 6.)

Now I want to calculate averages for each of A, B, C, D,E based on Identifier. To do that I used  **Process1**

```
avgcalls <- function(calls){
  totcalls <- sum(calls)
  out <- totcalls/6
  return(out)
}

avgcallsdf <- data.frame((aggregate(X[, 1:4], by = X[6], avgcalls)))
```

The output looks like this

```
  Identifier        A          B    C     D
1          a  1.66667  1.6666667  2.0   2.5 
2          b  0.50000  0.8333333  0.5   0.5
```

Alternatively I did(please suggest a better way to do this)
**Process2**

```
samp1<-D[which(D$Identifier=='a')] #creating one dataframe with identifier as 'a'  
samp2<-D[which(D$Identifier=='b')]#creating another dataframe with'b'as identifier  

#calculating means   
mean1<-sum(sampl$A, na.rm=TRUE)/6  
mean2<-sum(sampl$B, na.rm=TRUE)/6  
mean3<-sum(sampl$C, na.rm=TRUE)/6  
mean4<-sum(sampl$D, na.rm=TRUE)/6
mean5<-sum(samp1$E, na.rm=TRUE)/6
finaldf<-data.frame(mean1,mean2,mean3,mean4,mean5)
```

similarly I do above with **samp2**
 Both results are identical.

My actual data has 1008 columns and around 80,000 rows, will the results vary from 
Process 1 and Process2 if there are NA's present?

I looked at this [Getting different results using aggregate() and sum() functions in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28602368/getting-different-results-using-aggregate-and-sum-functions-in-r) but it wasn't very helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a good way to solve this in `dplyr` in 2 lines.

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(A=c(1, 2, 4, 2, 0, 1),  B=c(2, 3, 5, 3 ,0, 2),  C=c(3, 2, 4, 4, 1, 1), D=c(4, 2, 5, 5, 2, 1),  E=c(5, 1, 3, 6, 3, 1), Identifier=c('a', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b'))  

df %>%
  group_by(Identifier) %>%
  summarise(A =  mean(A), B = mean(B), C = mean(C), D = mean(D), E = mean(E))
```

Should give you

```
  Identifier     A   B    C    D     E
      a       1.75 2.5  3.0  4.0  4.25
      b       1.50 2.5  1.5  1.5  1.00
```

(Notice my numbers are different than yours -- I'm hoping this is because you ran this over your entire dataset and not just the head like I did).

**EDIT:**
You could also do what @TheTime says, and save some ink:
`summarise_each(funs(mean))`

Comment: How does the dplyr solution scale to 1008 columns?

Comment: Good question. Maybe the OP can try and report back.

Comment: I'm assuming doing a microbenchmark() test give us a way to tell how dplyr scales in comparison to the others

Answer (score 3):

We can also use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, lapply(.SD, mean), Identifier]
#   Identifier    A   B   C   D    E
#1:          a 1.75 2.5 3.0 4.0 4.25
#2:          b 1.50 2.5 1.5 1.5 1.00
```

If we need the `sum` divided by `n=6`

```
setDT(df1)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) sum(x, na.rm=TRUE)/6), Identifier] 
#   Identifier        A         B   C        D         E
#1:          a 1.166667 1.6666667 2.0 2.666667 2.8333333
#2:          b 0.500000 0.8333333 0.5 0.500000 0.3333333
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution using "aggregate", with "a" as the data frame, assuming that the "Identifier" is in the last column:

```
aggregate(a[-c(ncol(a))], by=list(Identifier = a$Identifier), FUN=mean)
```

or more compactly, using the formula interface as pointed out by @thelatemail:

```
aggregate(. ~ Identifier, data=a, FUN=mean)
```

which gives:

```
  Identifier    A   B   C   D    E
1          a 1.75 2.5 3.0 4.0 4.25
2          b 1.50 2.5 1.5 1.5 1.00
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `aggregate` more simply by employing the formula interface.
Editing your function will also allow you to pass a `n=` for your denominator more easily:

```
avgcalls <- function(x,n) sum(x,na.rm=TRUE)/n
aggregate(. ~ Identifier, data=dat, FUN=avgcalls, n=6, na.action=na.pass)

#  Identifier        A         B   C        D         E
#1          a 1.166667 1.6666667 2.0 2.666667 2.8333333
#2          b 0.500000 0.8333333 0.5 0.500000 0.3333333
```

Comment: thanks a lot. this is nice. Will it be right to say that the aggregate function simply executes the steps of process2 but masks it?

Comment: @krazzyr - pretty much, yep